# Why does concatenation of a string an char in C++ return an empty string?

Tags: c++

Why does concatenation of a string and char in C++ return an empty string?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <assert.h>

int main() {
    std::string s = "hello" + '4';
    assert(s == ""); // why does s equal "" here?
}
```

Comment: It is not a concatenation, it is pointer arithmetic.

Comment: What do you expect as output ?

Comment: `"hello"` is not a `std::string`. Unfortunate, but there you have it.

Comment: Do you mean `assert(s == "hello4");` ? `assert(expr)` gives a runtime error if `expr` is evaluated to false.

Comment: @Laci -- the code means what it means; it's intended to show that the result is `""`. Some folks use `assert` in code samples as a shorthand for showing expected output.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is in

```
std::string s = "hello" + '4';
```

which doesn't do anything remotely similar to appending a `'4'` to a string.  The actual behaviour is completely different from your expectations.

The string literal `"hello"` is represented as an array of six `const char`, with values `'h'`, `'e'`, `'l'`, `'l'`, `'o'`, and `'\0'`.   (the last character is known as a terminating null).

The value `'4'` is a `char` literal that (assuming your compiler uses ASCII or compatible character set, which is not guaranteed by the standard) has a numeric value of `52`.

The expression `"hello" + '4'` is then seen by the compiler as `"hello" + (char)52`.   A `char` is an integral type, so the net result of `"hello" + '4'` is a pointer to the 53rd character of the string literal (which doesn't exist, since the string literal `"hello"` is represented as an array of six elements).

So the result of `"hello" + 4` is a pointer to a non-existent character.

The initialisation of `s` in `std::string s = "hello" + '4';` then passes that pointer to a constructor of `std::string`.   That constructor incorrectly ASSUMES it is passed the address of the first character of a null terminated string.   That's not what is passed, so the result is undefined behaviour.

The assertion `assert(s == "")` is not actually guaranteed to be true.   It happens to be true, with your compiler and on your host system.  But, because undefined behaviour has occurred, any result is possible  (including, notionally, reinstalling your operating system in the process of initialising `s`, and never reaching the `assert()`).

To do what you intend, you need to force the compiler to work with `std::string` objects in the right hand side (rather than pointer arithmetic).  One option to do this is

```
 std::string s = std::string("hello") + '4';
```

This works by constructing a `std::string` from the literal `"hello"`.   `std:string` supports an `operator+()` that can be used to concatenate a `char` to a `std::string` (and returns a `std::string` that is used to initialise `s`).

The above works with all C++ standards (since 1998).  A second alternative (since C++14) is to use the literal notation

```
std::string s = "hello"s + '4';
```

which works in essentially the same way (the `s` in `"hello"s` forms a literal of type `std::string` rather than one represented as an array of `char`, so the result of addition is also a `std::string`).

The reason things are like this is historical.

Comment: Or `std::string s = "hello"s + '4';`

Comment: @Elijay - Yes, true (at least, since C++14).   I'll edit to note that shortly.

Answer (score 3):

In C++, end of a string is marked by zero byte.

Consider this code:

```
const char* str1 = "hello"; // Length is 6 bytes
const char* str2 = str1 + 52 // Numerical value of '4'
```

`str2` is now a pointer past the end of the string. Accessing that memory location is undefined behavior, but if there happens to be 0 in that memory location, then `str2` is equal to an empty string.